# sql - creacion de campo con tipo de dato masculino/femenino

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando una tabla clientes, con varios campos. A uno de ellos llamado sexo, quiero establecer como valor que se pueda colocar masculino o femenino. Existe algun tipo de dato que de la posibilidad de solamente esas dos respuestas? o eso se programa posteriormente con por ejemplo python donde recoja la informacion sobre el sexo, dando la posibilidad de solo colocar masculino o femenino?

Comment: Puedes usar el [tipo de datos `ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) o definir un `tinyint` que acepte por ejemplo `1` para masculino y `2` para femenino o un `char` de una posición que acepte sólamente `m` o `f` o un booleano. Cabe decir que `ENUM` tiene varias ventajas, porque tienes definido de entrada lo que el campo debe y puede aceptar, mientras que en las otras opciones tendrás que controlar, en la definición de la tabla o por código que sólo acepte los dos valores posibles.

Comment: También puedes crear una FK referenciada a otra tabla que contenga únicamente los valores que te interesen.